# LinkClicked event not firing for LinkLabel in a scrollable Panel in C# after using mouse wheel

Tags: c#, events, panel, mousewheel, linklabel

I'm working in Visual Studio Express 2012, making a C#-based WinForms application. I have a Panel containing a LinkLabel with a maximum width, causing a vertical scroll bar to appear on the panel when required (the text in the label is built at run-time).

I can use the mouse wheel to scroll up and down through the label contents correctly, but if I use it to position the scroll bar slider anywhere other than the very top, and then click on a link, the LinkClicked event of the LinkLabel doesn't fire (or at least, the event handler is never reached -- breakpoints placed there don't activate). If I use the arrow buttons on the scroll bar instead, everything works as it should.

How do I make the LinkClicked event fire after using the mouse wheel to scroll? Why doesn't it work out of the box?

Comment: it does not fire because you dont see what should happen or maybe it fires but it does not make what it was supposed?,try placing a breakpoint in the eventhandler,just asking because you didnt say if you already try it.

Comment: I had already checked that -- it's how I knew the event wasn't firing, but I see exactly why you asked! Question is updated...